# Can't open html after clicking button with Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I basically have a base.html with three buttons and what I want to do is every button click opens a respective html view.

```
base.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>User Management</h2>
   <br>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Create New User</button>      
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Deactivate User</button>      
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Change User Password</button>      


  {% block content %}
  {% endblock %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have 3 other html files extending the base.html
This is one of them:

```
deactivate_user.html


{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block header %}
  <h1>{% block title %}Deactivate User{% endblock %}</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container mt-3">
  <h3>Deactivate User</h3>
  <br>
  <form action="{{ url_for('deactivate_user')}}" method='POST'>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="username" name="username" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

and this is the flask code

```
@app.route('/deactivate_user', methods = ('GET', 'POST'))
def deactivate_user():
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        username = request.form['username']
        error = None
        if not username: 
             error = 'Username is required.'
             
        if error is None: 
            flash('User has been deactivated successfully.', 'success')

        flash(error, 'error')
    else:
        return render_template('deactivate_user.html')
```

However, I am unable to link the button click with the app route path.

I tried the onClick method in the button tag but this only accepts javascript.

I need it to get sent as a GET request to the /deactivate_user app route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you allowed to change the button to an anchor tag?

```py
<a class="btn btn-info btn-lg" role="button" href="{{ url_for('deactivate_user') }}">Deactivate user</a>
``
```

Comment: thank you. that worked. but I will need to have it as a button or at least make it look like one. (that's my first time working with HTML). Also the anchor tag messed up the extended html by making them all anchored.

Comment: @OmarHesham Updated the post to make the link look like your button

Comment: thats exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much.